# How to prove the following interesting fact about positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

if $M$ is a real positive definite matrix, $S$ is a real vector, we define $\mathbb{sign}(S) = [\mathbb{sign}(s_1),...,\mathbb{sign}(s_n)]^T$. How to prove the fact that $S^TM\mathbb{sign}(S)$>0?

Comment: I presume $sign(s_i) = 1$ when $s_i > 0$, $0$ when $s_i = 0$ and $-1$ otherwise? Only for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessarily true.  For instance, consider
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&-2\\-2&10}, \qquad S = \pmatrix{9\\1} \quad t > 0
$$
We compute
$$
S^TM\operatorname{sgn}(S) = -1 < 0
$$

Comment: Ah, this is much better.

Comment: @user1551 There's no $2 \times 2$ example with the diagonal entries equal (at least I don't think there is), so I got stuck for a bit

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Counterexample:
$$
M=\pmatrix{
16&-14&-11\\
-14& 35& -5\\
-11& -5& 41},\ S^T=(5,1,1),\ S^TM\operatorname{sign}(S)=-4.
$$
One can easily verify that $M$ is positive definite using Sylvester's criterion.

**Remark.** Let $S$ be entrywise positive. Then $S^TM\operatorname{sign}(S)=S^TM\mathbf1$. Since a positive definite matrix may contain negative off-diagonal entries, $M\mathbf1$ can have negative elements too. Therefore it is implausible that $S^TM\mathbf1$ is always nonnegative.

Comment: Neat! How did you find that counterexample?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Just rejection sampling. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Fair enough ${}{}$

Comment: I made a wrong guess. The original problem is something about balanced graph. Maybe I should  reconstruct my problem.